# How do I enforce a write-once then read only database table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Is it even possible?

My use case is a ledger table, with a requirement that once a record is created, it should be read-only, i.e. no-one should be able to edit or delete it. This only applies to the ledger table and tables with a direct relation to it - there are other tables in the same schema which will be updated/deleted as normal.

My understanding is that for data integrity purposes these sorts of constraints should be applied at the database layer, but I can't find a clean, widely accepted way of doing this - is this a use case where I'd just be better doing it in the application layer?

The ideal would be for a way to do it in plain SQL, so as to be agnostic of what DB platform is used, since that may be subject to change, but I realise that may be too much to ask for, so if it has to be platform-dependent, some flavour of MySQL is preferred.

Thank you!

Comment: It might not be the proper way of doing it, but you could remove all grants from the database user, and only allow `INSERT` and `SELECT` actions? If the user is restricted from executing `UPDATE` and `DELETE` commands agains the database / table, would that be sufficient?

Comment: Can that be done on a per-table basis so it wouldn't impact the user's ability to update/delete in other tables?

Comment: It sure can. [Here are some docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant-tables.html). You can specify individual permission grants, per user, per table. You could even allow updates to individual rows of the table and not others.